# How to create a tab bar in addition to the nav bar

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I have an RMQ ruby motion app. Additionally, I have a screen with UINavigation in it (`ProfileController)`. i.e. it has `< Back <title>` navigation on top. On a button click on the screen, I would like to open a new screen with two tabs (`HomeController`, `HomeController2`). But on this new screen I want to keep the navigation I have i.e. `< Back` should take user back to the previous screen.

For tabs I am using Promotion to display the two tabs. To open the tabs, I'm doing this on button click: `open_tab_bar HomeScreen, HomeScreen2`. This all works very well but I lose the navigation when the tab `HomeScreen`  shows app.

This is the code

```
class ProfileController < PM::Screen
...
  def show_tabs
    open_tab_bar HomeScreen, HomeScreen2
  end
...
end

class HomeScreen < PM::Screen
  title "Home"

  def will_appear
    @view_setup ||= set_up_view

    self.title = "One"
  end

  def set_up_view
    set_attributes self.view, {
      background_color: UIColor.whiteColor
    }

    set_tab_bar_item system_icon: UITabBarSystemItemFeatured

    true
  end

end


class HomeScreen2 < PM::Screen
  title "Home"

  def will_appear
    @view_setup ||= set_up_view

    self.title = "One"
  end

  def set_up_view
    set_attributes self.view, {
      background_color: UIColor.whiteColor
    }

    set_tab_bar_item system_icon: UITabBarSystemItemFeatured

    true
  end

end
```

As you can see there is no navigation on top

[image]

**Question**

Is there a way to add navigation stack d

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do that with the stock UITabBar. As ProMotion's docs say, it opens the tab bar as the root view controller:

[https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion/wiki/API-Reference:-ProMotion::Tabs#open_tab_barscreens](https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion/wiki/API-Reference%3a-ProMotion%3a%3aTabs#open_tab_barscreens)

> Opens a UITabBarController with the specified screens as the root view controller of the current app. iOS doesn't allow opening a UITabBar as a sub-view.